# How to create a modal popup that only shows if IE is being used?

Tags: internet-explorer, modalpopups

I ask because I don't know, please go easy on me :)

I have created a site in Joomla and works pretty well on all browsers except for IE (of course)

Is there a way to have a pop up (modal or banner) that only shows with IE users to advise this website is best viewed in anything but IE?

In addition to your awesome response, could you go so far as point out where it should be placed (the code that is)

cheers

Comment: Hi lain, you need to debug your joomla site your self or hire professional services that develop and debug joomla web sites and that have experience with cross-browser quirks. You could improve the response to your question by 1. adding joomla to its tag list. 2. Adding a publicly accessible link to your website and a screen shot of your website as viewed in your IE. It may be that your website appears just fine on other ppl's computers, but only on your computer in IE, because of your IE settings for Compatibility View (Tools>Compatibility View Settings) ,it appears with rendering artifacts.

Comment: Tools>Compatibility View Settings>remove localhost or the domain of your joomla site from the list if they have been placed there, check "Include updated website lists from Microsoft". Save changes. Next Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default", finally Tools>ActiveX filtering .... make sure you test with ActiveX filtering turned on and off.